# Merge [resistance] into [damage-resistance]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we merge (and make synonyms) the [resistance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resistance) and [damage-resistance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/damage-resistance)?

Answer (score 10):

No.

Systems have a variety of different types of resistance, including magical, arcane and normal weapons and not all of these relate to damage.

Comment: Given there's a whole 70 questions about damage-resistance, I think it's very much earned its own specific tag on the topic, too. :)